# Html: How to put two images one above the other in the same line with text?

Tags: html, css, image, text

Is there a way to put two images one above the other in the same line with text?  This example for three lines, and the second line has two images one above the other after the words "of text" and then continue the text normally?  whether using css or a table or anything?

[image]

I tried putting them in a div or an image block, but nit sure how to implement it.  They can be put one above the other in a table cells, however tables doesn't go side by side with text, they can be either float right or left of a paragraph, not in the middle I think.

Example pictures links: [1](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_-6FYKDSRJ2Qz8CTZLADbDgHmPaGKQjBMhbCqgEbgR7YkR7mS), [2](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTZYEcLppt4iu9tRNmH0KpP-_AZL62ZSgk8P36_4jG--MMXRg1xag).  You can use them to make an demo in jsfiddle.net or something if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/kb1tc9r4/11/

Here is a solution where the css code uses flexbox to achieve that

```css
.images {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text <div class='images'>
  <img width='20' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_-6FYKDSRJ2Qz8CTZLADbDgHmPaGKQjBMhbCqgEbgR7YkR7mS'>
  <img width='20' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTZYEcLppt4iu9tRNmH0KpP-_AZL62ZSgk8P36_4jG--MMXRg1xag'>
</div>text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
</div>
```

Comment: It shows the images starting in a new line, not in the middle of the line with text before and after

Answer (score 2):

Using `line-height` and `display:inline-block`

```css
p{
  line-height:40px;
  
}
span{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
img{
  width:20px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<p>Is there a way to put two images one above the other in the same line with text? This example for three lines, and the second line has two images one above the other after <span><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_-6FYKDSRJ2Qz8CTZLADbDgHmPaGKQjBMhbCqgEbgR7YkR7mS"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTZYEcLppt4iu9tRNmH0KpP-_AZL62ZSgk8P36_4jG--MMXRg1xag"></span> the words "of text" and then continue the text normally? whether using css or a table or anything?</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y7notgbp/

You just a tiny css and html. Setting height of images to 0.5em makes sure your images fit into the line. Outer element needs inline-block set to display property while images need block set to the display property.

```
.inline-images{
  display: inline-block;
}
.inline-images img{
  height: 0.5em;
  display: block;
}


Blaaa  

<span class="inline-images">
  <img src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/58afdad6829958a978a4a693.png"> 
  <img src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/58afdad6829958a978a4a693.png"> 
</span>

blaa
```

Comment: Please click the `[<>]` snippet editor and post the code here. No need to leave SO for this